# What is the word for someone who sells pictures or works of art?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Is there any specific word for describing **someone who sells pictures, drawings, paintings, or works of art** in English?
(Oh and also this "someone" trades (or deals(?)) paintings as well.)

There are lots of words for someone who just sells things, such as "seller, dealer, merchant,
but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Wouldn't there be a better choice than "picture-seller"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I know them as [art dealers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_dealer) (Wikipedia):

> An art dealer is a person or company that buys and sells works of art. Art dealers' professional associations serve to set high standards for accreditation or membership and to support art exhibitions and shows.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use **gallery owner** as art galleries are typically where such sales are conducted

Comment: A gallery owner does not necessarily sell paintings.

Comment: @Drossel and people who sell paintings may not necessarily have a gallery.